# Xpath: select content from a specific <span> inside an <div>

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

I have the following source code:

```
<div class = "price-text--price-part--Tu6MH udlite-clp-discount-price udlite-heading-xxl" data-purpose = "course-price-text">
     <span class = "udlite-sr-only"> Current Price </span>
     <span>
           <span> 47.99 </span>
     </span>
</div>
```

Now I want to get as a result: 47.99 using xpath. How Can I do that ?

Comment: There are a number of XPath statements that can work. Knowing the requirements or variability of the data can help target the value or make it more resilient to changes in the HTML. For instance, whether to anchor to any of those attributes, if the price always follows the span with the text "Current Price", whether you want to trim leading and trailing whitespace, etc.

Answer (score 3):

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div/span[2]/span').text
```

Pro tip: to find the XPath of an element on a website you can use inspect element, right click the element you want the XPath for, select copy, then copy XPath.

Comment: Thank you. But what if I have a lot of divs on site and what to look into specifcally this div with name? I tried: 

element = chrome_driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@data-purpose='course-price-text']/span[2]/span").text
print(element.text)

But I receive NoSuchElementsException.

Comment: @WoutervandenBroeke, the NoSuchElementsException exception is from the call to find_element_by_xpath. The print hasn't had a chance to execute.

Comment: Yes, he must've edited his comment, because that detail was not clear at the time of commenting

Comment: For the HTML example you provided it worked fine selecting the span using your code. Maybe the page wasn't fully loaded yet when the `find_element_by_xpath` line was called. Try adding a delay.

Comment: Exactly! Adding some time before finding element worked fine. Thank you.